# Telerik RadGridView CustomValidator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I’m using RadGridView, and im trying to add a custom validator on ‘Username’ TextBox in EditMode.
The customvalidator is working but I couldn’t get the value of the username insert by the user!

This is my code:

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemCreated
    If (TypeOf e.Item Is GridEditableItem AndAlso e.Item.IsInEditMode) Then
        Dim item As GridEditableItem = CType(e.Item, GridEditableItem)
        Dim editor As GridTextBoxColumnEditor = CType(item.EditManager.GetColumnEditor("Username"), GridTextBoxColumnEditor)
        Dim cell As TableCell = CType(editor.TextBoxControl.Parent, TableCell)
        Dim validator As CustomValidator = New CustomValidator
        Dim valSumma As ValidationSummary = New ValidationSummary
        validator.ControlToValidate = editor.TextBoxControl.ID

        Dim boolUser As Boolean = False
        Dim query = "Select * from Employee where Username = @Username;"
        Using MyConn = New SqlConnection(GlobalVariable.ConnectionString)
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand(query, MyConn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", USERNAME TEXTBOX VALUE)
                MyConn.Open()
                Using readerObj As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    'This will loop through all returned records 
                    While readerObj.Read
                        boolUser = True
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        If boolUser = True Then
            validator.IsValid = False
        Else
            validator.IsValid = True
        End If
        validator.ErrorMessage = "Username Already Exist"
        validator.Text = "*"
        cell.Controls.Add(validator)
        cell.Controls.Add(valSumma)
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help please.
I want to replace ‘USERNAME TEXTBOX VALUE’ with something that get the textbox value!
I tried ‘cell.text’ , editors.text’ but nothing is working.
Thanks!!

Comment: I start by saying I don't use Telerik, but any chance the text is empty - since this is the `ItemCreated` event, would you not check validation in an edit event?

Comment: Try the ItemDataBound event, ItemCreated is too early and data is not populated yet in the rows.